# Spinner with drawSelectorOnTop

Tags: android-layout, android-widget

What is the purpose of drawSelectorOnTop in a Spinner?
Whether I set this flag to "true" or "false", I cannot see any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, like the name says it displays the selector control on top of the contents of the Spinner.

Whether or not there will be visual differences will depend on the style/contents of the Spinner. This is an example.

[image: this]

You'll note that the selector control appears to be on top of the Spinner

Answer (score 5):

**Spinner does NOT support android:drawSelectorOnTop, as it does not use a selector**, 
from Romain Guy from Google

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/c0OcLBrxsaU