# Android spinner view

Tags: android-widget

Iam new to android development..
I had a doubt that while using spinner view, we are including an attribute as **android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"** . Can anyone explain me the reason for use of this attribute

```
             <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spinner with drawSelectorOnTop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460864/spinner-with-drawselectorontop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property indicates whether to mark it as selected using a color (Orange in case of emulator) once the item in the list gets selected by the user.

Please refer the below image:

http://www.edureka.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/custom-spine.jpg